# applying velocity to rigidbody makes it float instead of dashing

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, 2d, rigid-bodies

Im trying to code so that my Character dashes to the right when pressing the Left mouse button, but instead of dashing it just starts slowly glieding or lets say floating.
This is the code i´ve used;

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
    rb.velocity = Vector2.right * DashSpeed;
    }
```

Im not sure but a other part of my code might be the reason for this problem but if so i would like to know how i could solve it. Thats the part im talking about

```
 rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
```

thats the code im using for movement.

```
    void Start()
{
 
    cam = Camera.main;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}
private void Update()
{

    horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded == true)
    {
        float jumpVelocity = 7f;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity;
        jumpsound.Play();
    }


    Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightAlt))
    {
        Dashing();
    }
        
 


}
void FixedUpdate()
{   
    
    

    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, CheckRadius, whatisGround);
    moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Main menu");
    }
    
    
}

void Dashing()
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * DashSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

}
```

Comment: Try using [addForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html). Directly affecting velocity is generally not a good idea when dealing with multiple inputs. Force will apply an acceleration relative to the mass of your object over time. You can apply multiple forces and the physics engine will resolve it giving a more realistic output.

Comment: @TEEBQNE if i try ´ rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * DashSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);´ basically nothing happens there isnt any force applied.

Comment: I am not sure what the other parts of your code look like, so it could be being overpowered by the velocity you are setting elsewhere. What is the value `DashSpeed`? Have you tried putting a very large value for it? If you are directly writing velocity elsewhere in your code, then that is the issue. Post all other code you are changing velocity for.

Comment: @TEEBQNE i´ve set it to 50000 and it still doesnt do anything. And on that Part with other velocities thats the code i have. i posted it under this post.

Comment: ty for your answer but i dont really understand how i should edit my code so it wont override everything.

Comment: I'll post an answer then to help clarify.

Comment: I added an answer it should point you in the right direction. If you are still unsure of what the issue is I can expand my answer. I gave you the snippet for your movement code which should allow the dash to at least appear. I left the dash and jump code to you. If you still can't get it, I can append to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current code is you are directly changing velocity in a few places. Some basic physics, the integral of position vs. time graph is velocity, and the integral of velocity is acceleration vs. time. To get a more realistic movement, it is better to apply a Force to objects. When doing this, the physics engine Unity uses can add a new force at a given time, then using acceleration can accelerate the object in that direction over time, then can change the velocity over time which will result in the position changing over time.

The example code you posted, you are directly setting velocity in a few places.

- `rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity;` (Jump)
- `rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);` (Movement)
- `rb.velocity = Vector2.right * DashSpeed;` (Dash)

When directly setting these values, the new values overwrite the old ones. As your movement code is not in any sort of if conditional it will continually write to the velocity causing the dash to never change anything regardless if you use add-force or change velocity directly.

I would consider making both your jump and dash use AddForce, and if you like the feel of your movement by applying velocity directly, then add the velocity do not set it.

Your previous line `rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);` would then become `rb.AddForce(new Vector2(moveInput * speed, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);`. Similarly you can update your jump and dash to match this. Let me know if you get this working or have more questions.

Comment: Damn thanks a lot im pretty sure i´ve understood it all, so i would have to rework my entire movement code through changing all velocity changes to force adding and the code should theoratically work. But by the way wouldn´t adding force make the movement feel sloppy or lets say drifting ?

Comment: Try it out it has been a while since I've done 2D movement. The ForceMode2D.Impulse applies the force in a single frame. If the movement still feels sluggish I can modify my answer a bit so you can still directly alter the velocity. The impulse force is generally used for explosions so let me know if the movement feels wrong.

Comment: Okay i will definetly try this thank you a lot. i will answer on this thread again if there are any problems regarding the addforce mechanic.

Comment: I would also try using `ForceMode.VelocityChange`. I forgot about it. It does something similar to impulse but disregards the mass of your object.

Comment: well ive tried to use addforce and it went very weird, my character accelerates instead of moving on a set pace and my jump doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Did you try the varying force modes in the last parameter?

Comment: And if the movement slowing down is too slippery, you can try to add a physics material with friction to your ground or player to slow the player down gradually. If you want, you can also add a counter force when there is no additional forces being added to slow the player down. I would say friction is the easier of the two as it is handled for you.

Comment: no i did not i edit it as following.(Look at the origial question)

Comment: Gotcha. I would try messing with the last parameter then and seeing if changing it to ForceMode2D.VelocityChange gives you the desired result. Sorry just checked the docs, turns out 2D only has Force and Impulse. I would change it back to setting velocity, but instead of directly setting it, add the new velocity to your existing velocity.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a problem with your animation. Link to a thread on unity answers:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/674516/rigidbody-character-problems-constant-floating-jum.html
You should go over to the animation place and hit bake into pose.

You should use the Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2, ForceMode2D). What this does is moving the GameObject in the direction of the Vector2, with the force mode of ForceMode2D. What is different about this from just translating it, is that it interacts with physics and improves the quality of your game. Here is a link, and the script:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
float dashSpeed;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
         rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * dashSpeed);
    }
}
```

And if the other part of the code you were talking about, if that is glitching, then do the same trick.

Comment: ty for your answer but as i replyied earlier to another comment using .addforce doesnt work i´ve already tried it.

Comment: Explain in more detail: does it have an error? Does it still float? Etc. also edit you original post with the full scripts

Comment: well it doesnt give any errors out and the game starts as normal but the force isnt applied on button press.The Player just floats on its current y value as long as i hold the button.

Comment: There is no issue with your code Ken. It is properly using AddForce. The issue is in the original code block posted, velocity is continually being overwritten in FixedUpdate, so this AddForce is being negated.

Comment: Oh, okay. Anyway if that doesn’t solve it, then I found this thread and posted the link in my edited answer.

Comment: i think the problem was solved through another comment thanks a lot tho if the problem still isnt solved i will definetly look into the thread. Oh btw do you have any good learing websites or apps for C# using unity.

Comment: The best c# learning website is W3Schools, and for unity, just go through docs.unity3d.com looking at anything interesting. Make sure to use W3Schools, because basically everything you learn there has a very good use in unity.